# After continue statement i dont see any console printing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to js.After continue statement i dont see any console printing.
I thought continue will move to next number or something else will happencan you guys tell me why its not working.I am providing my code below.

```or-tag-here
var String = "paa"
//var String = "pak"
var splittedString = String.split()

console.log("outside outer loop");

for(i=0;  i<splittedString.length; i++) {

    var c = splittedString[i];

    console.log("outside inner loop");

    for(j=0; j<splittedString.length; j++) {

        console.log("inside inner loop");

        if( i === j)
        {
            console.log("inside if condition");
            continue;
        }

        console.log("c ---------->" + c);
        console.log("splittedString[j]---------->" + splittedString[j]);

        //console.log("inside inner loop");
        if( c === splittedString[j] )  {
        //else if( c === splittedString[j] )  {

            console.log("inside comparison");

            console.log("not unique string");
            break;
        }

        else {
            console.log("its an unique string")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You've heard of the concept of paragraphs right?

Comment: `String` is reserved. don't use it

Comment: @j08691 can you update in my code...its confusing :(

Comment: @MehulMohan can you update in my code...its confusing :(

Comment: hey thanks for your help I got it working jsfiddle.net/at661zsu

Comment: @j08691 hello can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600110/minimise-the-code-since-i-am-using-the-same-code-only-the-content-in-p-tags-chan

Answer (score 0):

Your code works "fine". The reason there is no console log is, that you have only one iteration. In that iteration both `i` and `j` equalst to `0`.

Try `console.log(splittedString)`. You will get your string in an array. I guess what you wanted to do was `var splittedString = String.split('')` (split it with "empty" character").

Although looping through array of characters is equivalent to looping through string itself. No need to split the string. You can do `splittedString  = String` and the result in this case will be the same as if you split it.

And as others mentioned try to avoid using variable names that could incline variable type (in your case `String`). Even if the code works, it is harder to read.

Comment: hey thanks for your help I got it working jsfiddle.net/at661zsu