# HTML tags passed within string not rendering fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- I am new to js,
- I have a drop down slider working fine.
- Content shows fine with p tag
- but within that p tag i need to add another link or list tag
- If I give it displays the whole a tag but it doesnot render like a normal web page. since I am giving a string. content={PLAYER.accordion(ballInfo, 

  "qwe

  testing

  "

  )}
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below

```or-tag-here
     static accordion(ballInfo, content) {
        if (ballInfo.isRetrieving) {
            return (





 <AccordionHeader className="jump-player-question-title jump-submenu-dropmenuHeader" header="ball ball ball ball sjsdsdkjjksddjks?" content={PLAYER.accordion(ballInfo, "qwe <p> testing</p>")} />

 <AccordionHeader className="jump-player-question-title jump-submenu-dropmenuHeader" header="dsknjdsncjdnsjkcsdnjcsdncjkdsn" content={PLAYER.accordion(ballInfo, "asd <a href="#">testing 2</a>")} />
```

Comment: Try `content={PLAYER.accordion(ballInfo, (<div>qwe <p> testing</p></div>))}`. The `content` parameter of accordion should now be valid JSX.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not a react expert, but can you try with this, replace

```
<p> {{content}} </p>
```

With this

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}} />
```

Comment: so if I give a tag within p tag will it come as a link

Comment: @Xp Uncaught ReferenceError: marked is not defined
    at Function.renderContent (accordion.jsx:19)
    at ACCORDION.render (accordion.jsx:40)
    at ACCORDION.<anonymous> (makeAssimilatePrototype.js:15)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:587)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:607)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as _renderVali

Comment: @xp I googled for the error but couldn't see any solutions :(

Comment: @xp: hey it worked...was it previously expecting marked library??

Comment: Yes, it was, but it's not necessary on this case, it was for other thing

Comment: so whats the problem

Comment: This is not the correct way to do what you're after. My comment, as above:

Try `content={PLAYER.accordion(ballInfo, (<div>qwe <p> testing</p></div>))}`. The content should now be valid JSX, and should render in `{content}`. JSX requires a single root, which is why I've added the `<div>`. You could change this to any other element, such as `<span>`

Comment: @furious but it was rendering html as string

Comment: @texirv
Look at my suggestion above, that is the correct way to pass markup (JSX) as a parameter and have it rendered as HTML.

Comment: @xp can't I do it using dangerously set html??

Comment: @texi, FuriousD os giving you an advice about Jax valid syntax, it's not about not rendering the html, is about best practices. Every html that you want asign on the content parameter, just add then inside a div or a span as the parent of all the content. That's the advise of furiousD, the other part of the code is good 

Comment: @xploshioOn hay can you help me with this one...I even debugged http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669937/debugged-the-code-i-think-it-will-be-this-function-onselect

Comment: @xploshioOn using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` unnecessarily, as in this case, is not a good practice.