# debugged the code I think it will be this function onSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- I had working code in react class
- but when I changed to React.Component the whole UI is breaking.
- **debugged the code I think problem will be this function onSelect**.
- since if I give console statements its not printing anything.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- i even checked the css it is same.

  providing code below

```or-tag-here
class Accordion extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a working solution here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/66/)

It seems that React.cloneElement prepends a modifier onto the props that are assigned. So instead of having a prop "_onSelect", it is being prepended by "$Accordion"

A working function call on those props looks like this:

```
this.props.$Accordion_onSelect(this.props.id);
```

To remove the $Accordion addition, don't start the prop key with an underscore. If it's just 'onSelect' then it will be passed as 'onSelect'. Here's the [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/67/)

Comment: I have never seen $ symbol in react...is it anyway can we avoid https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html

Comment: you changed at other places also can you tell me the reason at this line too           onSelect = this.onSelect;

Comment: You could pass the onSelect and Selected values from the parent and pass them down through React component context [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). And I added the onSelect reference just checking to make sure that the scope was being maintained before I discovered the props name change, you can set it back to a direct set and it will work fine.

Comment: is there anyway can we remove $ symbol

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer and provided another JSFiddle. You just need to remove the underscores on the property keys you're creating in cloneElement.

Comment: so when we use underscore do we need to use $

Comment: Yes it appears that React's cloning function will handle keys that begin with an underscore in that manner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142869/discussion-between-texi-rv-and-michael-lyons).